# I want to clone with default values clonenode()

Tags: javascript, php, html, clonenode

I want to do is to clone a row in a table. Here the code:

```
function addRow(){ 
    var x=document.getElementById("insertar").tBodies[0];  //get the table
    var node=x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);    //clone the previous node or row
    x.appendChild(node);   //add the node or row to the table
}
```

I just do not want to clone this section which, because when I add data to the first row, when you clone, data are also cloned.
I pated the HTML code:

```
<table id='insertar'>
                <tr><td>Producto</td><td>Stock</td><td>Cantidad</td></tr>
                <?php 
                $numeroItems = 1;
                try{
                    $prod = array();
                    $param = array('TIPOP'=> 'Productos');
                    $ready = $client->MOSTRARPRODUCTOS($param)->MOSTRARPRODUCTOSRESULT;
                    array_push($prod,$ready->PRODUCTOS);
                }catch(Exception $e){
                    echo $e->getMessage();
                }
                echo "
                <tr><td>
                <select id='p' name='producto[]' onChange='document.getElementById(\"stock\").value = setStock()' >";
                echo "<option value='' >---------</option>";
                if(count($ready->PRODUCTOS)>1){
                    for($j = 0;$j < (count($ready->PRODUCTOS)); $j++){
                        if($ready->PRODUCTOS[$j]->GRUPO==$_GET['grupo']){
                            echo "<option value=".trim($ready->PRODUCTOS[$j]->CODIGOP)." >".trim($ready->PRODUCTOS[$j]->CODIGOP)."</option>";
                        }
                    }
                }
                echo "
                </select><br />
                </td>
                <td><input type='text' id='stock' value='' name='stock[]' readonly></input></td>
                <td><input type='text' name='cantidad[]' required></input></td></tr>";
                ?>
            </table>
            <a href="#" onclick="addRow()" >Agregar otro</a>
```

Now I want to change attributes td so that they are unique, how would you?
Example of clones:

```
<tr><td>.....</td><td id="stock1" ...></td></tr>
<tr><td>.....</td><td id="stock2" ...></td></tr>
<tr><td>.....</td><td id="stock3" ...></td></tr>
Etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should clone your default node right before it gets modified. Then reclone `default` as needed in your `addRow`.

```
var _default;
window.onload = function(){
  _default = document.getElementById('defaultNode').cloneNode(true);
}
```

like so:

```
function addRow(){ 
    var x=document.getElementById("insertar").tBodies[0];  //get the table
    x.appendChild(_default);   //add the node or row to the table
}
```

---

Your proposed working solution:

```
var _default;
window.onload = function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("insertar").tBodies[0];
  _default = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
}
```

Edit2:

```
var counter = 1;
function addRow(){ 
    var _cloned_default = _default.cloneNode(true);
    _cloned_default.id = "stock" + counter;
    counter++;
    x.appendChild(_cloned_default);   //add the node or row to the table
}
```

Simply get the td element in your cloned element:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(_cloned_node.childNodes, 0).forEach(function(value){
    //making sure it's a node and nothing else
    if(value.nodeType === 1){
        //change id here
        value.id = counter;
        counter++;
  }
});
```

Comment: It worked like this:

`var _default;
window.onload=function(){
  var x=document.getElementById("insertar").tBodies[0];
  _default =x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);   
}`

Comment: Now I want to change attributes td so that they are unique, how would you?

Comment: @AbrahamMorales suppose _default is a td ? (in the end I am unsure what you are cloning). Simply clone your _default into a variable and change the id. **_cloned_default.id = "stock1"**

Comment: if I do that, the throne of td id is changed, how would you do?

Comment: @AbrahamMorales it's hard to understand what you want. "throne of td" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: according to the code that shows the cloned tr be published. What I want is that the td is edited, not the tr

Comment: or how it is done to look for a label on the cloned object?